Laravel : Storage::Delete on Json Array
$projectphotos = [];
$photocount = 1;
if ($request->hasFile('project_photo_url')) {
    foreach ($request->file('project_photo_url') as $file) {
        $currentDateTime = now()->format('YmdHis');
        $filename = $initials . "_" . $photocount . '_' . $currentDateTime . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Buat nama unik untuk setiap file
        $file->storeAs('public/project/photos', $filename); // Simpan file ke direktori yang diinginkan
        $photocount++;
        $projectphotos[] = $filename; // Simpan nama file dalam array
    }

    $projectPhotos = json_decode($project->project_photo_url);

    if (!empty($projectPhotos)) {
        // Menghapus file-file terkait dari penyimpanan
        foreach ($projectPhotos as $photo) {
            Storage::delete('public/project/photos/' . $photo);
        }
    }
    $project->project_photo_url = json_encode($projectphotos);
}

$project->save();

my code is like this, but I got an error
| json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given
where my data is like this
["opot_1_20240419230832.png","opot_2_20240419230832.png"]

I want to delete existing data, but it keep adding new but ignore delete the old one
Tried not using json_decode, but it doesn't delete the existing

$projectPhotos = json_decode($project->project_photo_url,true); try it

It says $project->project_photo_url is already an array. If you var_dump or Log::info($project->project_photo_url);, what do you get? You may have a casts or accessor on $project turn decode project_photo_url
